# Unprecise number of POST parameters to controller

Tags: java, playframework

I have a serach form of 2 types:

1. With pre-defined parameters count.
2. With unprecise parameters count, meaning that for each different entry type in my DB i will have different searchForm(which will consists of textfields mostly).

If the form number 1 is not so hard to do, then form number 2 is quite confusing

P.S. Currently I understand that this kind of form might be implemented with some kind of AJAX request, where JS transform data into JSON, but how to do it with regular post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *params* map in the Controller to retrieve the values. See [the documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#paramsmap). For example:

```
public static void search() {
    String name = params.get("name");
    String[] tags = params.getAll("tags");
    // ... etc ...
}
```